# View list of YouTube videos shared with me

Tags: youtube

My friend has shared a lot of his private videos with me. Every time he shares a video, I get an email with a link through which I can watch the video. But I cannot find a place in YouTube where the entire list of videos shared with me is displayed.

Can anyone help me with how to see a list of all private videos shared with me?

Comment: There is no option to show the  list of videos shared by others in youtube,Since you are getting email notification every time when your friends shared the videos you can get the list of all shared videos.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw a "History" option on the left side of the YouTube page. You can see a list of the videos previously watched. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just ask your friend to make a playlist and put all of those videos together, he can share that playlist by changing option to "unlisted". After that he can give u the link and u will have all of those shared videos in one place. Hope this helped.